# how can i access objects and call objects method?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

So i was building a game were i have the player jumps, and if the player lands on a crate or a an enemy the player jumps by a function on Collision (using a collision detector another game object to detect collision). The collision is registered, although the function is not executed, after a bit of debugging i noticed that the object(scripts) that i'm calling are not there when i play they are null, and it gives nullReferenceException.

Collision detector class:

```
public class CollisionDetector : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool collide=false;
    public rogueMovement ro;
    public Crate cr;
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag=="enemy")
        {
            Debug.Log("Jumpoff enemy");
            collision.collider.GetComponent<rogueMovement>().jumpOffEnemy();
            collide = true;
        }
        else if (collision.collider.tag=="crate")
        {
            ro.isJumping=false;
            Debug.Log("Crate collision");
            cr.Die();
        }

    }
}
```

the function i wanted it to execute:

```
public void jumpOffEnemy()
{
    //ani.SetTrigger("jump");
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, Verticaljump), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    //transform.Translate(0f,5f*Time.deltaTime,0f);
    Debug.Log("jump");
}
```

here are before playing, and after playing images  of what is happening with collision detector game object where i placed the Crate script and rogue class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyAPi.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8lJl.jpg)

Comment: Well, seemingly `GetComponent<rogueMovement>()` is returning `null`.  So you need to address that.

Comment: Yes i did. if you check the images i posted, the object returning null after playing the game, although before playing the game its alright with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using collision.**gameObject**.GetComponent().jumpOffEnemy();

It should fix your primary issue. Other than that, you need to initialize rogueMovement and Crate as Unity won't understand where to get and change values of those scripts when game starts as scripts can be attached to any and multiple gameObjects, unless they are ScriptableObjects and not MonoBehaviours. Simple fix for it would be as follows:

```
public GameObject x;
public GameObject y;

rogueMovement ro;
Crate cr;

Public void Start()
{
    ro = x.GetComponent<rogueMovement>();
    cr = y.GetComponent<Crate>();
}
```

Attach x and y GameObjects where those scripts are.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm no longer working on this project since its advanced, and i'm new to game development.I appreciate your answer, i will try after i finish my current project